# Documentation defines usePrevious without a dependency array, why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

This is a copy-n-paste from: [Hooks FAQ usePrevious](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });  // no dependency arg, why?
  return ref.current;
}
```

Since `useEffect` is called without a dependency array, its function argument will be called for every render.  Is it safe to limit this to only when `value` changes by adding `value` to the `useEffect` dependency array, like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
```

I'm wondering if there is some scenario where `ref.current` must updated every render, which would explain the omission of `[value]` from the documentation.

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, "every render" basically means whenever the `value` variable changes anyway since there is only one `useState` hook. So adding `value` to the deps array would make no difference in this case. Omitting it doesn't make a difference either since it's never being run with the same values (only after a change to `count` in the parent function).

If there was another `useState` somewhere which was causing another re-render, then yeah adding `value` to the deps array would cut down on `ref.current` updates.

Comment: Thank you ChronoLink.  That completely answers my ponderings.  Cheers!